# Translation of "tus ojos mirándome"

Tags: significado

How does this translate to English? And, what verb form is 'mirándome'?

According to Wiktionary.com:

> Compound of the adverbial present participle of mirar, mirando and the pronoun me.

Whaaaaat! Hahaa.

I'm thinking that this is something that has no direct translation to English, which is why I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around this one.

BTW, the context is the song *Eres para mí*:

> La sombra que pasa
>
> La luz que me abraza
>
> Tus ojos mirándome
>
> La calle que canta su canto de diario
>
> El mundo moviéndose

Comment: Your eyes look at me?

Comment: That's just *your eyes looking at me.*

Comment: @B.ClayShannon it would be "Your eyes look**ing** at me". Notice the word is the verb "mirar" plus ending "-ando" (-ing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have yourself your own answer.

It translates as:

> Your eyes looking at me.

That form is called *gerundio* (present participle); the *gerundio* of *mirar* is *mirando*. It is possible (and necessary) to put two words together to form one. So it is wrong to say *mirando me*, instead you have to say *mirándome*. The *tilde* (accent mark) is there because the accent is in the second syllable, so when you put the two words together the accent is still there, but now you have an *esdrújula* word. But maybe that's a point for another question.

Unlike English, you don't use a preposition with the verb *mirando* when it's reflexive.

That applies to all the conjugation of that form:

> Mirándome
>
> Mirándote
>
> Mirándose
>
> Mirándonos, etc

You can say for example

> Mira la luna. *Look at the moon*, or even *he/she looks at the moon*.

In that case the verb is not reflexive. But you could say

> Mirándome a mí.

In that case you put emphasis that she/he is/was looking at you, and to no one else.

Comment: I feel so silly now! I'm very familiar with the gerund form of verbs. I didn't recognize it as a gerund form because I was thrown off by it also being reflexive (along with the accent mark). Thanks for another great explanation!

Comment: It's better to be *silly* sometimes in order to learn a language. If you are not afraid of that, you will succeed, so don't worry.

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson Seen as a reduced relative clause: *your eyes looking at me* (= which are looking — tus ojos que están mirándome), but that's hardly used. We often use gerunds in Spanish with this intention, same as in English.

Comment: Just a little thing: this is not a reflexive construction. It is true, though, that you don't use a preposition before the accusative form of the pronoun (*me*).

Comment: Thanks for the editing, I didn't notice I wrote *aguda* instead of *esdrújula*. I wanted to explain that the first word was *aguda* but then it becomes *esdrújula*, I just didn't write the whole sentence.